# Play framework can't read variable assigned by a #{set} tag into a #i{if} tag?

Tags: java, if-statement, playframework, global-variables, scope

I have a problem with PlayFramework 1.2.5 and my question is:

How can I use a variable that be assigned by a #set{.../} tag into a #{if .../} tag?

This is my java code - (it works):

```
...
renderArgs.put("blockInsert", true);
...
```

And this is my htm code - (it works):

```
...
#{set allowInsert:"${!blockInsert}" /}
...
```

Reading variables with ${} and #{get/} - (it works):

```
blockInsert == ${blockInsert}<br/>
allowInsert == #{get 'allowInsert' /}<br/>
```

Using variables on #{if/} tag - (it not works well):

```
using variable from renderArgs - (it works) 
#{if blockInsert}
    cant't insert
#{/if}
#{else}
    can insert
#{/else} 
<br/>

using variable from #{set} tag - (it not works) 
#{if allowInsert}
    can insert
#{/if}
#{else}
    cant't insert
#{/else}
...
```

When I run this page the output is:

```
blockInsert == true
allowInsert == false 

using variable from renderArgs - (it works) cant't insert 
using variable from #set} tag - (it not works) can insert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
%{allowInsert=!blockInsert}%
```

instead of set.
The Result of the set tag is a String. Or you adjust the if statement:

```
#{if allowInsert == "true"}
    can insert
#{/if}
#{else}
    cant't insert
#{/else}
```

Comment: The solution for me was to adjust the if statement because my intention was  pass values ​​to a custom tag(without passing as parameter to the tag) and use them in a if statement...
You helped me so much!!!
Thank you!